# How do I iterate through an array of ranges in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, range, enumeration

If you have an array of ranges, such as `[1..4, 7..11, 14..18, 21..25, 28..28]`, what options do I have for iterating through the elements?

I could do

```
ranges.each do |range|
  range.each do |date|
    puts "Do work on February #{date}"
  end
end
```

which is a bit verbose, or I could do

```
dates = ranges.map(&:to_a).flatten
dates.each do |date|
  puts "Do work on February #{date}"
end
```

which could use a lot of memory if the ranges are large.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Is there any chance of ranges overlapping?

Comment: They don't overlap in my scenario, but if they did, I'd like it to be done once.

Comment: In that case, your first example seems pretty clean to me. I'll be interested to see if someone has something even simpler though.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't think your first answer is too verbose, but if that pattern is getting used often enough, it might make the case for something like this -

```
module Enumerable
  def each_node
    each do |x|
      (x.respond_to?(:each_node)) ? x.each_node{ |y| yield(y) } : yield(x)
    end
  end
end

[[[(1..5)], (1..2)],1].each_node { |x| print x }  #=> 12345121

ranges = [1..4, 7..11, 14..18, 21..25, 28..28]
ranges.each_node{ |date| puts "Do work on February #{date}" } #=>as expected
```